# Two android applications with same sharedUserId and process

Tags: android, shared-data

I've got a question about android applications with same android:sharedUserId and android:process attributes.

**would you please tell me, when should we use applications in the shared process and how can we access data on other application in that process?**

Answer (score 0):

**android:sharedUserId** - This is deprecated now, you should avoid using this

> when should we use applications in the shared process

Ideally whole application process should not be shared with another application and there won't be much use-cases of it as well
Android components such as Activity/Receiver etc should be made to run in a separate process as opposed to application process basis some use-case, like we used separate process for running our FCM service to reduce memory footprints while initialising reducing our ANR's

> how can we access data on other application in that process

You can use Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) for this
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl

Comment: I know separating process of components in an application, but what about two applications using same process? is any other solution except using AIDL?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your use-case of using same process for two apps?

Comment: According to the Android documents [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element)
By setting this attribute to a process name that's shared with another application, you can arrange for components of both applications to run in the same process — but only if the two applications also share a user ID and are signed with the same certificate.

Comment: So I can not understand how can two application in the same process, communicate  with each other?